# Delete an element when a key of element is not found by jq

Tags: json, select, jq

I want to delete some elements when a specific key is not found using jq.  In below json file, I need to delete the first and second items as they don't have the key "Case".

```
[
  {
    "label": "US : USA : English",
    "Country": "USA",
    "region": "US",
    "Language": "English",
    "locale": "en",
    "currency": "USD",
    "number": "USD"
  },
  {
    "label": "AU : Australia : English",
    "Country": "Australia",
    "region": "AU",
    "Language": "English",
    "locale": "en",
    "currency": "AUD",
    "number": "AUD"
  },
  {
    "Case": "1",
    "label": "CA : Canada : English",
    "Country": "Canada",
    "region": "CA",
    "Language": "English",
    "locale": "en",
    "currency": "CAD",
    "number": "CAD"
  }
]
```

And the output would be:

```
[
  {
    "Case": "1",
    "label": "CA : Canada : English",
    "Country": "Canada",
    "region": "CA",
    "Language": "English",
    "locale": "en",
    "currency": "CAD",
    "number": "CAD"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Just figured out my solution:

```
del(.[] | select(.Case == null))
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by keeping the elements that have `.Case` defined.

```
map(select(.Case != null))
```

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/fTN3KrtsG4)

If `.Case == false` won't be encountered, the above simplifies to

```
map(select(.Case))
```

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/3HUFjEifxT)